# How to tell GCC to place an inline assembly instruction at a specific position?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, bootloader

I am working on the bootloader for a processor architecture that is based on [ORPSoC](http://opencores.org/or1k/ORPSoC). To execute a program, the bootloader loads it into memory and then jumps to the beginning of that program.

Now I need the custom instruction `l.cust1` inserted in the delay slot of the jump. This instruction is implemented by the processor and activates decryption of the following instructions. That is the reason why it *has* to be placed in the delay slot. Any later, and the program could not be executed, as its instructions are encrypted. Similarly, if the decryption is activated too early, the bootloader crashes because it is not encrypted.

I am now wondering whether it is possible to tell GCC where to place the `l.cust1` instruction. Currently I have to manually modify the bootloader binary accordingly.

Inserting inline assembly `__asm__("l.cust1\n\t");` in the bootloader's C source code results in the instruction being added somewhere before the relevant jump:

```
1fc2e10:       9c 21 01 b4     l.addi r1,r1,436
1fc2e14:       70 00 00 00     l.cust1         # switching on decryption
1fc2e18:       18 40 01 ff     l.movhi r2,0x1ff
1fc2e1c:       9c 72 ff ff     l.addi r3,r18,-1
1fc2e20:       a8 42 7c 94     l.ori r2,r2,0x7c94
1fc2e24:       9c 90 00 04     l.addi r4,r16,4
1fc2e28:       85 62 00 60     l.lwz r11,96(r2)
1fc2e2c:       48 00 58 00     l.jalr r11
1fc2e30:       9d c0 00 00     l.addi r14,r0,0
```

However, I need it to be located in the delay slot of the jump:

```
1fc2e10:       9c 21 01 b4     l.addi r1,r1,436
1fc2e14:       9d c0 00 00     l.addi r14,r0,0
1fc2e18:       18 40 01 ff     l.movhi r2,0x1ff
1fc2e1c:       9c 72 ff ff     l.addi r3,r18,-1
1fc2e20:       a8 42 7c 94     l.ori r2,r2,0x7c94
1fc2e24:       9c 90 00 04     l.addi r4,r16,4
1fc2e28:       85 62 00 60     l.lwz r11,96(r2)
1fc2e2c:       48 00 58 00     l.jalr r11
1fc2e30:       70 00 00 00     l.cust1         # switching on decryption
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `l.cust1` in the same inline assembler statement as the jump, which must be declared `volatile` as it has side effects and have `"memory"` in the clobber list as it depends on the contents of memory.

Comment: Yes, after @esm 's  answer, I figured, I'd probably have to do the jump in inline assembler as well. I will update here as soon as I have time to test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `asm volatile` and an artificial dependency to the code that you wish the inline assembly to proceed.  The example taken from the [gcc documentation is below](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

```
asm volatile ("mtfsf 255,%1" : "=X"(sum): "f"(fpenv));
sum = x + y;
```

According to the documentation `volatile` alone is not enough.  In other words the compiler still might change the order of the following code:

```
asm volatile("mtfsf 255,%0" : : "f" (fpenv));
sum = x + y;
```

By adding the dependency you ensure the placement of the inline assembly.  In the first code snippet by adding a dependency on `sum` it is ensured that the compiler will not reorder the code as it believes it will be generating a different result due to the dependency.  You can find another example of this on [this webpage](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html) in the "C code optimization" section.